# SQLite and Decimal128

Tags: sqlite

Decimal128 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal128_floating-point_format), is not natively supported in SQLite.

I could store the number as TEXT, and search by casting to REAL, but that means I would lose precision (REAL uses just 8 bytes in SQLite, https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), which means the search could yield invalid results.

What could be a workaround for this?

Thanks,

Juan

Comment: What are the operations that you need to perform on such type? Only compare for equality or also, say, compare for greater / smaller ?

Comment: Yeah, basically I just need to do basic comparison between 2 decimals while searching (<, <=, =, >, >=), using the decimal column as index.